# Ajuda a comprender o Resto da Divisão

Tags: java, divisão

Boas,
Estou com alguma dificuldade em perceber o resto da divisão, consigo calcular e chegar ao valor do resto e compreendo a formula, mas no exemplo de código descrito abaixo estou com alguma dificuldade em perceber como é que o resto da divisão ajuda a identificar se um número é par ou ímpar.
Agradeço desde já a quem conseguir ajudar, sei que provavelmente é algo simples, mas não estou mesmo a conseguir perceber.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class cond02 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int N = sc.nextInt();
        
        if (N % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("PAR");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("IMPAR");
        }

        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: basta você pensar que qualquer numero dividido por por 2 sobra zero, 2 / 2 sobra zero 4 / 2 sobra zero e qualquer numero impar divido por 2 vai ter resto, caso continuar com a dúvida recomendo dar uma revisada em operações básicas de divisão.

Comment: Note que a operação resto da divisão é uma operação que se aplica a números **inteiros**, assim `m % n` dará como resultado um número inteiro entre 0 e n-1, o resto da divisão de m por n. Para o caso específico de `m % 2` o resultado poderá ser ou 0 ou 1. Caso seja 0 significa que `m` é divisível por 2 e portanto par e caso contrário é ímpar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olha, pense assim: matematicamente, quando um número é divisível por outro, tem-se que o resto da divisão dá 0.
Por exemplo: 10/2 = 5 , e resto = 0. Agora, 11/2 = 5 e resto = 1. Se o número é par, ele é divisível por 2, já um número ímpar não. Então, se o resultado de (N % 2 == 0), como no exemplo de (10/2), for 0, tem-se que ele é par. Caso contrário (como no exemplo de 11/2), ele é ímpar.

Answer (score 0):

Vou tentar te explicar o mais resumidamente possível:

Todo numero PAR que for dividido por 2 sempre terá resto 0, caso contrario o numero é impar.